# Declaring a boolean variable as NULL in C++

Tags: c++, null, boolean, nullptr

Can I use `null` or `nullptr` as a `bool` value instead of `0`/`false`?
Since declaring a `bool` as `null` means that the `bool` value is actually `zero`/`false` and that does not work in my case. I am using `zero`/`false` as another possible outcome. I would like to have a bool value that can be 'non existent' (neither true nor false).

Comment: You want to use a type that has two possible values to represent more than two possible values. That seems like it'll end in tears. Use a different type that can represent all the values you care about.

Comment: http://thedailywtf.com/articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at [boost::optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/tutorial/a_note_about_optional_bool_.html) or [boost::tribool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/tribool/tutorial.html#idp471873200)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use boost in your project, then `boost::optional` is for you. It works like Haskell's `Maybe` if you're familiar with that.

Simple examples of use (from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/examples.html):

```
// return values
optional<char> get_async_input()
{
    if ( !queue.empty() )
        return optional<char>(queue.top());
    else return optional<char>(); // uninitialized
}

void receive_async_message()
{
    optional<char> rcv ;
    // The safe boolean conversion from 'rcv' is used here.
    while ( (rcv = get_async_input()) && !timeout() )
        output(*rcv);
}

// local variables
optional<string> name ;
if ( database.open() )
{
    name = database.lookup(employer_name) ;
}
else
{
    if ( can_ask_user )
        name = user.ask(employer_name) ;
}

if ( name )
    print(*name);
else print("employer's name not found!");
```